# Updating a record in MS Access is not working with SQL Syntax

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Could you please help me with this.
I have these codes..

```
Private Sub dgvInTraining_CellClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvInTraining.CellClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        Dim transID As Integer = Me.dgvInTraining.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value

            UPdateInTraining(transID, Now)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub UPdateInTraining(transID, timeOut)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        query = "UPDATE InTraining SET TimeOut = @timeOut WHERE TransID = @transID"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, cnn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transID", transID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeOut", timeOut)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        GetErrorMessage(ex)
    Finally
        CloseConnection()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I am able to save just fine but when I try to update the record I created, it doesn't change the values in the database. My database definition follows:

```
TransID AutoNumber
ID Text
TimeIn Date/Time
TimeOut Date/Time
WithWater Yes/No
TransDate Date/TIme
```

Comment: OleDB doesnt use named parameters other than as placehiolders.  Swap the order of the `AddWithValue` lines so that you are adding the values in the same order they appear in the SQL

Comment: I'm not getting it Sir. What do you mean?

Comment: I got it!!!! Thank You Plutonix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OleDB` simply uses parameters as placeholders (the names do not matter/are ignored), so you have to take care to add them in the **same exact order** as they appear in the SQL.  Your SQL uses the order `@timeOut` then `@transID`:

```
"UPDATE InTraining SET TimeOut = @timeOut WHERE TransID = @transID"
```

But you are adding them in the opposite order:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transID", transID)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeOut", timeOut)
```

It will be looking for a TransID of whatever the timeout value is. Swap those lines and it should work barring any other issues.

---

Note that [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggests using `"?"` as a placeholder<sup>1</sup>.  Doing so will force you to look back at the SQL to see which to add next. But using `?` will not fix adding them in the wrong order.

Especially when there are several parameters, I prefer to use "`@p1, @p2...`" style parameters.  The numeral helps index the column names in the SQL and you can visually see that you added them in the right order:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", strBar)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", nFoo)
```

<sup>1.  In fact they say `?` must be used.  This is not true, it just does not map values to names but relies on the order added.</sup>

Comment: I would recommend to use the question mark `?` as a placeholder instead when using OleDb, as documented on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This prevents other developers who modify your code (including yourself in a few years from now) from making the same mistake.